# Running an Action if part of a file changes

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

What is the recommended way of running some `Action` if part of a file changes?

My use-case is given a file that I know exists (concretely `elm-package.json`), run a shell command (`elm package install --yes`) if part of the file changes (the `dependencies` field).

It seems that the `Oracle` abstraction exposes comparing a value to the last (via `Eq`). So I tried a `newtype` like:

```
newtype ElmDependencies = ElmDependencies () deriving ...
type instance RuleResult ElmDependencies = String
```

But now, I get stuck actually using this function of type `ElmDependencies -> Action String`, since the rule I want to write doesn't actually care what the returned String is, it simply wants to be called if the String changes.

In other words,

```
action $ do
    _ <- askOracle (ElmDependencies ())
    cmd_ "elm package install --yes"
```

at the top-level doesn't work; it will run the action every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `askOracle` approach is pretty close, but Shake needs to be able to
identify the "output" of the action, so it can give it a persistent name
between runs, so other steps can depend on it, and use that persistent name to avoid recomputing. One way to do that is to make the action create a stamp file, e.g.:

```
"packages.stamp" *> \out -> do
    _ <- askOracle $ ElmDependencies ()
    cmd_ "elm package install --yes"
    writeFile' out ""
want ["packages.stamp"]
```

Separately, an alternative to using `Oracle` is to have a file
`elm-package-dependencies.json` which you generate from
`elm-package.json`, write using `writeFileIfChanged` (which gives you `Eq` for files), and depend on that
file in `packages.stamp`. That way you get `Eq` on files, and can also
easily debug it or delete the `-dependencies.json` file to force a rerun.